# How Can I Decorate a Parametric Curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, gnuplot, shading

I'm trying to draw a special parametric curve, but my results are not good enough, because I'd like to decorate it. So, I've tried this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.3cm,y=0.3cm]`
`\clip(-20.,-20.) rectangle (20.,20.);
\draw[fill=blue!50!black,fill opacity=0.10, smooth,samples=1000,domain=0.0:31.29] 
plot[parametric] 
function{(8.0+5.0)*cos((t))-5.0*cos((t*(8.0+5.0)/5.0)),(8.0+5.0)*sin((t))-5.0*sin((t*(8.0+5.0)/5.0))};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I'd like to have another result. Something like this:

[image: Maths]

How could I get that kind of result shading with blue color? And are there other kind of techniques easier than this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly the same picture but I think it's a good way. With the next update of tkz-base and euclide. I added

```
    \def\tkzClipOutPolygon(#1,#2){\clip[tkzreserveclip] (#1)
               \foreach \pt in {#2}{--(\pt)}--cycle;
            }
```

and

```
   \tikzset{tkzreverseclip/.style={insert path={%
     (\tkz@xa,\tkz@ya) rectangle (\tkz@xb,\tkz@yb)}}}

   `\tkz@xa`etc. are defined by `tkzInit`
```

The code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/P1,1.5/0/P2}
        \foreach \i [count=\j from 3] in {2,...,7}{%
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[P\i]({45*(\i-1)}:1.5 cm){P\j} 
        }
         \tkzClipOutPolygon(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8)
         \tkzCalcLength[cm](P1,P5)\tkzGetLength{r}
        \begin{scope}[blend group=screen]
            \foreach \i in {1,...,8}{%
                \pgfmathparse{100-5*\i}
                \tkzFillCircle[R,color=MidnightBlue!\pgfmathresult](P\i,\r)
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{document}
```

[image]

It's a little more complex

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10]
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/P1,1.5/0/P2}
        \foreach \i [count=\j from 3] in {2,...,7}{%
            \tkzDefShiftPoint[P\i]({45*(\i-1)}:1.5 cm){P\j} 
        }
         \tkzClipOutPolygon(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8)
        \tkzDefMidPoint(P1,P2) \tkzGetPoint{Q1}
        \tkzCalcLength[cm](Q1,P5)\tkzGetLength{r}
        \begin{scope}[blend group=screen]
            \foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,...,8}{%
                 \pgfmathparse{mod(\i,8)+1} 
                 \let\k\pgfmathresult
                 \tkzDefMidPoint(P\i,P\k)
                 \tkzGetPoint{Q\i}
                    \pgfmathparse{100-5*\i}
                    \tkzFillCircle[R,color=MidnightBlue!\pgfmathresult](Q\i,\r)
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The centers of the circles are the middle of the sides and the circles go through opposite vertex

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible starting point.

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3) (0:1) foreach~in{1,...,7}{--(~*360/8:1)};
    \foreach~in{0,...,7}\fill[blue] (~*360/8:1) circle(2);
    \foreach~in{0,...,7}\fill[white, opacity=.28] (~*360/8:1) circle(2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]